# Esterification of phosphonic acid chloride is working with isoprenol but not with prenol

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, organophosphorus-compounds

I am performing an esterfication reaction between an activated phosphonic acid (chloride) and a series of alcohols. Until now, I was not able to make the reaction work with prenol, while isoprenol is working fine. I am wondering, what could be the reason for such different chemical behaviour and reactivity? I tried different solvents like THF, DCM and acetonitrile and also bases like pyridine, NaH as well as DBU and DMAP, but until now, me only observed the isoprenol adduct. Isoprenol is working with absolute standard conditions. Is there anything you can recommend I haven't tried? Would you expect such different reactivity just by the positioning of the double bond?

[image]

Comment: I would not expect any difference in the reactivity of the two alcohols. Have you checked on the purity/identity of your prenol?

Comment: Yes, booth are fairly pure regarding NMR.

Comment: You could try adding 1eq of a silver salt e.g. AgBF4

Comment: If you use an aqueous workup, is solvolysis occuring?

Comment: @user55119 No, the isoprenol adduct withstands aqueous workup. During reaction control you the correct product mass increasing in counts, while the educt is consumed. I was asking myself if somehow the reaction with the prenol is somehow energetically disfavored.

Comment: @Waylander I am wondering how this would work mechanistically? After the acid chloride is formed, the pyridine substitutes the chloride and you have a good leaving group. At which point does the silver speed up the process? (I did not find any mechanistically review on that yesterday)

Comment: The silver removes chloride ion from solution increasing the rate of formation of the pyridinium species

Comment: The prenol phosphate is allylic and more readily prone to solvolysis than the isoprenol phosphate, which is just a normal primary phosphate.

Comment: @user55119 until now, I did not observe it in LCMS reaction control therefore I did not bother to do an workup on the prenol ester.

Comment: [Tetrahedron Letters **1986**,*27*,1225](https://www.sciencedirect.com/search?authors=ziegler&cid=&issue=&page=1225&pub=tetrahedron%20letters&qs=&show=25&sortBy=relevance&volume=27) describes the reaction of (*R,E*)-2-methylhex-4-en-3-ol with *n*-BuLi in ether followed by quenching the alkoxide with diethyl phosphorochloridate [(EtO)2POCl]. It appears that the allyic phosphate was used without isolation. The alcohol is secondary and allylic and perhaps prone to solvolysis, more so than yours. Have you considered phosphorus NMR to follow the course of the reaction prior to isolation?

Comment: NMR service at my institute is not very accessible. Therefore I try to avoid this as RC as good as possible and relay mainly on LCMS and TLC and do this only for final characterization....I was thinking of trying microwave radiation as well as the addition of a silver catalyst like @Waylander suggested.

Comment: @user5511 What else I find confusing is the fact, that that tetrabutylammonium hydrogen phosphat can react seemingly easy alike with prenol and isoprenol with trichloracetronitril.